# Flexbox image and text

Tags: css, flexbox

I have some difficulties using Flexbox. What i want to achieve is to have 2 Items.

The First is an image (of any size) and the first item's size (height and width) should be same as the size of the image) while the 2nd item is a text, the width of the div of the text must be the remaining size of the container and the height should be the height of the image.

```
.container {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row;
}
.image {
  background: hotpink;
   max-width: 100%;
   width : auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 2;
  background: deepskyblue;
}
```

[Please see this](https://jsfiddle.net/ksLm5520/1/)

please let me know what happening to my code.

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what it is you are trying to do but the issue is, I suspect, that your wrapper / parent div is 100% wide and what is actually required is a "shrink-wrap" effect.

For this you would need `display:inline-flex` not `display:flex`...then things become much easier.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  background: hotpink;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/234/7/6/sample__50x50_blink_pony_icon_by_tripperwitch-d5c3pne.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Title.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-200-200-1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Title.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

One final point...see that the image has that extra space underneath?...That's a problem consistent with whitespace in the HTML taking up space. There are remedies for that which can be found on SO when dealing with the same issue with `inline-block` elements.